# pytesseract error when converting image to string

Tags: python, pytesser

I keep getting an error with the following code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = Image.open("book.jpg") # the second one
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print text
```

The error is:

```
File "demo2.py", line 9, in <module>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
File "/home/vagrant/src/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
config=config)
 File "/home/vagrant/src/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if this is an installation problem or something else.
I read the answers to [OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory using pytesser](/q/35609773), but they didn't help me.

Comment: does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but i managed to convert image to string.
using `apt-get` should do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

and if you can't use it in a python script just do this:

```
from os import system

system("tesseract -l eng /image.png text.txt")
```

Comment: For macos, `tesseract` is available for `brew install tesseract`.